# Can a loud HDD damage my other drive in a NAS?

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I am populating a 2-bay QNAP NAS on a budget, so I put a 2012' WD Green HDD in one slot, and I think of putting my 2008' WD Caviar SE next to it, but since the latter one is a really loud drive (27 dB in Silent Seek according to specs) I think maybe it's not a good idea.

How likely is it, that the vibration from a loud drive damages the silent one?

Comment: You might have more luck over at https://serverfault.com

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not worried about the loud drive?  Are you worried that its vibration will affect the other drive or that it may fail and corrupt the data on the other drive due to RAID?

Comment: Correct, except it's not a RAID but rather simply a separate volume on its own. I am worried it will corrupt the data physically by vibration. Also, it seems that it's not just loud, it's loud by design. I didn't measure the noise level at 27dB myself, I got this number from its specs. My newer WD Green drive is 0.3dB in silent seek by comparison. Also, I didn't use the old one for 9 years, so I don't remember whether it sounded different when it was new.

Answer (score 1):

Zero to none.  If just mirroring the 1st drive there is no risk other then losing the loud hdd. It could be the bearings going in the motor. You probably don't want to rely on it for data you actually care about.

Using old or used drives can be risky when your going for data redundancy.

Check the s.m.a.r.t status of the drive in question. It can give you clues as to when it will physically fail.

Comment: S.m.a.r.t. status is all right, except crc error count is marked as ”warning”, but that can't have anything to do with the noise, can it? Also, do you mean the risk is higher if I don't have redundancy? I am planning not to have it at the moment, the drives are of different sizes, and the data isn't precious.

Comment: If you have more content to add, please [edit] your existing answer instead of posting a new answer, unless it's entirely unrelated to your original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Raid 0 uses both disks for performance, while striping data across both disks. (You want to use two new disks for this that are the same size) raid 1 bit for bit mirrors everything that the first drive writes (this would be more suitable for using old disks) but you will be limited by the smallest disk. J.b.o.d is just a bunch of disks (no raid) more like a USB drive on a network. Hope this helps.. P.s cyclic redundancy check c.r.c errors are not a good sign of the drive lasting, it means that it's noticing that when it writes things, what was sent to the drive isn't always what was written. Get your stuff off of that drive!